# install win7 theme to kubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu

Im trying to install win7 theme to my kubuntu 12.04 system through console with the following commands but after the last command the system says that i must install zenity.how can i continue the installation.Thank you

```
cd $HOME
sudo wget http://web.lib.sun.ac.za/ubuntu/files/help/theme/gnome/win7-setup.sh 
sudo chmod 0755 $HOME/win7-setup.sh
$HOME/win7-setup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

How about installing the missing program:

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/zenity

zenit is there to "Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts" which I presume your install script needs.

Since the win7 theme requires you to run gnome you can either change the underlying ubuntu (if it is a fresh install and you don't mind re-installing) or you go and hunt for a KDE based win7 theme. There is some discussion here: http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=71972.0

Report back which one mentioned there worked for you.

---

It is not clear why you chose Kubuntu when now it turns out you want Gnome because for some reason you are keen on the win7 theme. [People have discussed the differences of KDE vs Gnome in detail.](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/unityplasma) Give it a read. If you think [you need Kubuntu but would like to install Gnome try this guide](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/gnome) which boils down to this.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Be warned that this will probably make for a messy mix of KDE and Gnome in some application menus. I'd advise to go for a Ubuntu (Gnome) re-installation if that's what you need anyway...

Comment: Please use http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/package_name instead, which creates a clickable link. Edited your answer to do so.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad: quite right. commandline user here so I copy and paste usually but this is of course prettier. thanks

Comment: but now  the problem is that i Please use the Gnome classic desktop for the Win7 theme installation.

Comment: I must use Gnome classic desktop.How can i do it in Kubuntu?

Comment: Yes @chris you have to use *Gnome*, why? because the theme is for *Gnome* not **KDE**.